# How to fix syntax error at or near "psql" in psql ubuntu

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, ubuntu, psql

I am entirely new to psql and not particularly familiar with some terms. I am following instructions on an ETL process for mimic-in the link here: https://github.com/chichukw/mimic-omop/blob/master/README-run-etl.md. When I run this code, it shows no output but this error:

syntax error at or near "psql"

I have tried adding semicolon, removing the psql part and removing the quotes and dollar sign but I still get this syntax error on the first character regardless.
[image]

```
psql "$MIMIC" postgres_create_mimic_id.sql;
```

I expect concept ids to be created after running this code on the server using the jupyter terminal.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot for better reference. Please see above image.

Comment: You are trying to run `psql` from within `psql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of how you could get that output/error is if you did this:

```
[root@foo /]# psql
psql (11.5)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# psql "$MIMIC" postgres_create_mimic_id.sql; 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "psql"
LINE 1: psql "$MIMIC" postgres_create_mimic_id.sql;
        ^
postgres=#
```

Instead, I think you should be doing this:

```
[root@foo /]# export MIMIC='host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres options=--search_path=mimiciii'
[root@foo /]# psql "$MIMIC" -f postgres_create_mimic_id.sql;
```

Disclosure: I am an [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://enterprisedb.com) employee

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out. Tried this instead:  psql -d mimic3 -a -f postgres_create_mimic_id.sql -U jupyter-chichukw